# What version of Bootstrap should/can I use for jQuery 1.8.3? (not v3)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

*Edit: I know that I cannot use Bootstrap version 3, because it requires JQuery 1.9.1.  I don't want to use that version of Bootstrap, I want to know what is the highest version of Bootstrap I can use with the constraint of jQuery 1.8.3.*

I am setting up a page within a site built on JQuery v1.8.3. I'd like to avoid upgrading JQuery if possible, because that would be far-reaching and complex.
I want to include Bootstrap on this page, but Bootstrap v3 requires JQuery 1.9.1+.

I haven't been able to find a chart that shows the different JQuery requirements across Bootstrap versions.

I have seen this site that keeps old Bootstrap documentation, but I don't see the requirements specifically spelled out here, either:

http://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.0.0

Comment: You could just upgrade jq version and include jquery migrate to use bootstrap v3, thats what you should do

Comment: I'll explore having a migration script.  Just, there's much content depending on earlier versions of earlier JQ and it wouldn't be safe to completely upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap v3's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3. For old versions, you can get the source code from  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases?after=v2.3.0

You can find the version of jQuery in sample files. For example, Bootstrap v2.0.0 used jQuery1.7.1. (bootstrap-2.0.0\js\tests\vendor) 
But I suggest you upgrade your jQuery version.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by only using the CSS from Bootstrap v3.  This sidestepped JavaScript compatibility issues.

For my particular project, Bootstrap's javascript library was unnecessary.

Comment: I dont understand how this question and/or answer can be help to other people.

Comment: Company X requires jQuery 1.8.3 and has a massive code base depending on this version.


Project Y within Company X is trying to use Bootstrap, but doesn't have the resources to update jQuery at this moment in time.

What do you do?  Given that Bootstrap and jQuery are arguably the two most popular front end libraries, I don't think this is an exotic circumstance, and I can imagine other people having this problem.  I think yanking out the Bootstrap JS is the lesser evil in this situation.  Not perfect, but it's a solution that worked.  No one else has given an answer.

Comment: Ok, but I think you dont understand the idea of stackoverflow. This is useless to anyone. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

The latest compatible version with 1.8.3 is bootstrap-3.0.3